# OCMockito: get SIGABRT in async when using MKTArgumentCaptor in a not called verification

Tags: ocmockito

```
- (void)test_pushRightController
    UINavigationController naviMock = mock(UINavigationController);

    XCTestExpectation *e = [self expectationWithDescription:@"xnothing"];

    self.model.navi = mockNavi;
    [self.model.buttonTapCommand execute:nil];

    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        MKTArgumentCaptor *captor = [[MKTArgumentCaptor alloc] init];
        [[MKTVerify(capabilityMock) withMatcher:[captor capture] forArgument:0] pushViewController:HC_anything() animated:YES];
        expect(captor.value).beInstanceOf([MyController class]);
        expect(((MyController*)captor.value).dataSource.pageType).equal(MyType);
        [e fulfill];
    });

    [self waitForExpectationsWithTimeout:5 handler:nil];
}
```

This will receive a `SIGABRT` if the verification failed(when `pushViewController:animated` not called),

if it is called, every thing is fine.

I replaced `dispatch_after` with `Specta's waitUntil`, but it still get `SIGABRT`.
Any idea?

Crash stack trace:

```
Thread 1Queue : com.apple.main-thread (serial)
#0  0x0000000115c4e0ae in __pthread_kill ()
#1  0x0000000115c15500 in pthread_kill ()
#2  0x00000001159bca44 in abort ()
#3  0x000000010cf70d39 in uncaught_exception_handler ()
#4  0x000000011066030b in __handleUncaughtException ()
#5  0x00000001148c703d in _objc_terminate() ()
#6  0x00000001157e726e in std::__terminate(void (*)()) ()
#7  0x00000001157e72e3 in std::terminate() ()
#8  0x00000001148c6fc5 in objc_terminate ()
#9  0x00000001158e64bb in _dispatch_client_callout ()
#10 0x00000001158d0f2d in _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF ()
#11 0x00000001105c02e9 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ ()
#12 0x00000001105818a9 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#13 0x0000000110580e08 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#14 0x00000001112043a1 in -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] ()
#15 0x0000000111243705 in -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] ()
#16 0x0000000128cf7ef6 in waitUntilTimeout at /Users/carmelosui/guoguoDev/Pods/Specta/Specta/Specta/SpectaDSL.m:177
#17 0x0000000128cf7c79 in waitUntil at /Users/carmelosui/guoguoDev/Pods/Specta/Specta/Specta/SpectaDSL.m:165
#18 0x0000000128c792f1 in -[MailSearchCompanySelectTest test_domesticsCommandTriggerGoSelectBlock] at /Users/carmelosui/guoguoDev/Cainiao4iPhoneTests/MailSearchCompanySelectTest.m:58
#19 0x000000011054e7ac in __invoking___ ()
#20 0x000000011054e5fe in -[NSInvocation invoke] ()
#21 0x000000011f822820 in __24-[XCTestCase invokeTest]_block_invoke_2 ()
#22 0x000000011f8557c2 in -[XCTestContext performInScope:] ()
#23 0x000000011f822770 in -[XCTestCase invokeTest] ()
#24 0x000000011f822c0b in -[XCTestCase performTest:] ()
#25 0x000000011f8208d1 in -[XCTestSuite performTest:] ()
#26 0x000000011f8208d1 in -[XCTestSuite performTest:] ()
#27 0x000000011f80dadc in __25-[XCTestDriver _runSuite]_block_invoke ()
#28 0x000000011f82e2e3 in -[XCTestObservationCenter _observeTestExecutionForBlock:] ()
#29 0x000000011f80da28 in -[XCTestDriver _runSuite] ()
#30 0x000000011f80e787 in -[XCTestDriver _checkForTestManager] ()
#31 0x000000011f856b23 in _XCTestMain ()
#32 0x000000011058bffc in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ ()
#33 0x0000000110581c85 in __CFRunLoopDoBlocks ()
#34 0x00000001105813e2 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#35 0x0000000110580e08 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#36 0x000000011687bad2 in GSEventRunModal ()
#37 0x00000001126e830d in UIApplicationMain ()
#38 0x000000010c58a994 in main at /Users/carmelosui/guoguoDev/Cainiao4iPhone/main.m:13
#39 0x000000011591592d in start ()
#40 0x000000011591592d in start ()
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the MKTArgumentCaptor?

Comment: @JonReid it will correctly report "Expected 1 matching invocation, but received 0", by the way, I'm using version 1.4.0